# Link to download facebook SDK for Mac OSX?

Tags: facebook, macos, sdk

Hi I am newbie to facebbok SDK. I need to download facebook SDK for Mac OSX. Please provide me the exact link and steps to use it.

Thanks,
Kapil

Answer (score 0):

Facebook haven't yet released a MAC OS X SDK,
you can find here the Facebook SDK's and other Open Source Projects,
https://github.com/facebook

An another way to build a MAC OS X Application is to use PhoneGap

**PhoneGap on the Mac (desktop)**
https://github.com/shazron/phonegap-mac

or you can use **Titanium Studio**
http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-studio/

both of them can build native mac applications.